# How to create a SQL Server table made up of averages of another table that doesn't lag?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

My SQL Server table is running particularly slow and I can't figure out why. This table has 7 columns, 5 of which are function scalars, which all calculate the daily averages of similar data in another table for a particular day. The first two columns are just timestamp per each day and itemId for a particular item that is creating data.

The first two columns are both primary keys, and the functions are deterministic but not persisted because the function uses user data, I suspect because I select from that raw data table in my functions, but this I am unsure of.

If I set the type of one of my columns as an average function, it will end up taking 5 seconds to calculate for 20 entries. This is too slow for our application and is causing errors. What is the best way to do this? if the current setup is the best, how can I reduce the lag that is being caused? I mainly want to avoid hardcoding the data like my coworkers want me to, as I need to figure out a way the SQL table will automatically fill itself every day, and for every new `ItemId` that is added to the raw data table.

Thanks!

I have already tried making the function deterministic, The user data is keeping me from making it Persisted which I think might be a possible speed boost as the averages generally don't need to change once they're done.

This is on a Microsoft Windows Server running SQL Server 2017

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DCP_AvgData]
(
    [AssetID] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [Time_Stamp] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceFlowYesterday] AS ([dbo].[AVERG]([Time_Stamp], [AssetID])),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DCP_AvgData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Time_Stamp] ASC, [AssetID] ASC)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AVERG]
    (--@floatVal FLOAT,
     @Time_Stamp DATETIME2(7), 
     @AssetID NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS FLOAT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar FLOAT
    DECLARE @result FLOAT
    DECLARE @time DATETIME2(7)

    SET @result = (SELECT MAX(Pump1Yesterday) 
                   FROM dbo.DCP_FloatData
                   WHERE @AssetID = AssetID 
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), Time_Stamp, 121) >= CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Time_Stamp)), 121) 
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), Time_Stamp, 121) <= CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), @Time_Stamp, 121) 
                     AND Pump1Yesterday>5);

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

The query takes about 5 seconds to load when I have 20 rows in it, which is horrendous as I'll need hundreds of rows and for it to at most be 1 second

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do with the date comparisons in your user-defined function?  I suspect that you're losing a fair bit of performance there, and that can probably be optimized.  I would also recommend calculating the averages overnight, and using a trigger to update a given average when the underlying data changes.

Comment: There are several questions that may give you your answers. (1) Is there an index on `AssetId`, `Pump1Yesterday`, and `Time_Stamp` in the table? (2) Why are you converting the value in `@Time_Stamp` from DateTime2(7) to DateTime2(7)? This is unneeded. In fact, the `CONVERT` format is unneeded in this context. See below for a better version of the code.

Comment: Also, this is returning a `MAX()` value, not an average. You would use the `AVG()` function for an average.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data types that you have specified above, the `CONVERT` statements can be entirely removed. Also, since the `Time_Stamp` compare looks to be "It must be the same day as the `@Time_Stamp` value, and no later in the day than that value", the entire query can be rewritten like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AVERG]
(
    --@floatVal FLOAT,
    @Time_Stamp Datetime2(7), 
    @AssetID nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar FLOAT
    SET @ResultVar=( SELECT MAX(Pump1Yesterday) FROM dbo.DCP_FloatData
        where @AssetID=AssetID 
        AND Time_Stamp >= CAST(@Time_Stamp as Date) 
        AND Time_Stamp <= @Time_Stamp
        AND Pump1Yesterday>5);

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

You should also have an index on your data source table (`DCP_FloatData`), and knowing what the data type of the Time_Stamp field is in that table would be helpful. I am assuming that it is `DATETIME2(7)` for this code.

Finally, your data source should have an index. One of these two indexes should be optimal based on the above code:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_DCP_FloatData_AssetId_Time_Stamp_Include
ON DCP_FloatData (AssetId, Time_Stamp) INCLUDE (Pump1Yesterday)

-- OR

CREATE INDEX Idx_DCP_DCP_FloatData_AssetId_Time_Stamp_Pump1Yesterday
ON DCP_FloatData (AssetId, Time_Stamp, Pump1Yesterday)
```

Which would be optimal depends on your data distribution, values, and row count, which I can't know from here.